# Performance issue in Angular 2 when I have an SVG into a ngFor

Tags: angular, performance, svg

To simplify my issue, let's say that I have 2 components:
A table and a cell component.

When I hover some kind of cells, I'm showing a pencil icon next to it that will allow me to edit in place the value.

```html
<!-- This is my table body -->
<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
    <td *ngFor="let column of columns; trackBy: trackByColumn">
        <app-cell [item]="item" [column]="column"></app-cell>
    </td>
</tr>

<!-- This is a part of my cell component -->
<div class="editinplace" (click)="edit()" *ngIf="column.inlineEditable">
    <svg-icon src="assets/edit_inplace.svg" class="svg"></svg-icon>
</div>
```

My cell component is rendered multiple times, and it might have a reference to an SVG file under some specific conditions.

That SVG file is very small (210B) and it's taking 1 second to load in Chrome (10 seconds in IE). So, I'm not sure what is my problem.

More info:

1) The cache is enabled

2) Looking at the Network tab the image is requested only once .

3) If I load the image alone, it's very fast. So I think it my be related to my ngFor.

Any ideas as to how to fix this performance issue?

[image]

Comment: If you ever come into some perf. improvement, please update your question with an answer. Im experiencing a similar issue

Comment: I wasn't able to find a good solution; I ended up adding a service worker on my application that acts as a cache and it improved the performance a lot. I still would like to have a reasonable answer for my problem.

Comment: @klewgenius same problem in my app only. Cannot replicate, fresh app and Stackblitz work fine with SVG's `use`. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svg-use-perf-issue?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing details of what `<svg-icon>` does behind the scenes and whether your icon has a single color, for highly repetitive use of a graphical element I would recommend converting that into an icon font - see https://icomoon.io/app/#/select

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. If I change my <svg-icon> tag for an <img> It causes the same behavior.